# Reauthenticating logged in user after extended period of time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase authentication for my app and I have the users sign up, login, and log out all set up and going. However, I'm a little confused on how to manage the state of the users login status. Currently, if a user is logged into the app, but doesn't use the app for an extended period of time, firebase doesn't recognize them as logged in. I'm looking at the documentation and the approach is a bit unclear.

Should I be storing a `FIRAuthCredential` every time the user logs in, and then call `reauthenticateWithCredential` using that credential?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Auth only requires recent sign-in for sensitive operations like: deleting a user, changing a user's email or password. These are for obvious reasons. You want to make sure it is the same user before making such sensitive changes. Otherwise, the user is considered signed in indefinitely by the Firebase Auth backend (your assumption that "firebase doesn't recognize them as logged in" is not correct). Of course, a developer may also require re-auth before other operations like updating credit card, shipping address, etc. A developer would check the `auth_time` on the Firebase ID token. Only in such cases would you re-auth. You should never store credentials such as password on the client to avoid prompting the user to reauthenticate. It is needed to protect the user's account.

Answer (score 0):

yes I think that is going to be right approach or second approach you can try is like when a user press login button instead of directly calling Authenticate User put a check in which last login timestamp value will be stored when user login compare timestamp value and then perform selected operation as you want . NOTE - you will be required to check weather user exist or not , but I think first approach will be better as if you had noticed in many Social apps like kik it ask for reauthentication after a long period of time but first it authenticate user instead of displaying home screen it take to reAuthenticate screen